# Can Movies & TV app on Windows open a video from a link?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, movies-and-tv

I know that there are some other modern media players. But Movies & TV performs quite well in terms of HDR. Now I found its only flaw perhaps is the lack of playing video from a link.

For example, an m3u8 link.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Streaming what and from where to where ?

Comment: An m3u8 link, for example. @harrymc

Comment: @ZhangWei - Edit your question instead of commenting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Movies & TV is a very basic Microsoft app that has very few features and options. It doesn't support any sort of links. It doesn't recognize `.m3u8` files if you add a folder with them, either - only the most known formats.

Use a very commonly utilized application like [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) instead. In that you can simply `File` -> `Open Network Stream` and paste the link.